# JQuery finding the right .next()

Tags: jquery

How can I keep going through `.next()`s until I find the one with the class or id I want?

`.next()` only searches the immediately succeeding sibling but I want JQuery to keep going until it finds the one I want **and only return that one**. In the below case, I'd like JQuery to return the bottom div:

```
$('.toggler').nextUntilOneIWant('.expand_me')

<a class="toggler"></a>

<div> some stuff </div>
...divs...
<div class="expand_me"></div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will look for all the next siblings of `.toggler` untill it finds '.expand_me` and will give only the element where it found this match.

```
$('.toggler').nextAll('.expand_me:first');
```

Comment: Is there any difference in performance/effect between using `.expand_me:first` and `('.expand_me').first()`?

Comment: `.nextAll` doesn't seem to return only one object. From JQuery: Get **all** following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. If filtered by `.expand_me`, wouldn't it return all `.expand_me`s?

Comment: Edited my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.toggler').nextAll('.expand_me').first()
```